# NTFS-3G permissions and inherit fstab flag

Tags: permissions, filesystem, samba, ntfs

I'm trying to user a NTFS filesystem with full ACS's set just like windows.

Everything is working fine except the permissions set to created files.

Here is my environment:

**fstab:**

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2E3219C021DD4D99 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data,defaults,permissions,inherit 0 0
```

**mount output:**

```
/dev/sda7 on /mnt/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096
```

**files and folders:**

```
marianna@server:/mnt/Data$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrws--- 1 root     data       0 Abr 28 13:34 Clientes
drwxrws--- 1 root     folhamatic  0 Abr 28 14:01 Folhamatic
drwxrwsr-x 1 root     data       0 Abr 28 13:59 Suporte
drwxr-s--- 1 marianna data      48 Abr 28 15:04 Treinamentos
marianna@server:/mnt/Data$ cd Treinamentos/
marianna@server:/mnt/Data/Treinamentos$ touch test.txt
marianna@server:/mnt/Data/Treinamentos$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marianna marianna 0 Abr 28 15:04 test.txt
marianna@server:/mnt/Data/Treinamentos$
```

The problem is I expect that the created test.txt have the group and permissions of parent folder. Is that a way to achieve that?

The folder "Treinamentos" already have the group sticky but it has no effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new setfacl feature is working for me. I set a default group permission on directories and now new files have that group.